# What causes my array address to be corrupted (change) when passed to function?

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

I am performing Compressed Sparse Raw Matrix Vector multiplications (CSR SPMV): This involves dividing the array **A** into multiple **chunks**, then pass this chunk by reference to a function, however only the first part of the array (**A[0]** first chunk starting the beginning of the array) is modified. However starting from the second loop **A[0 + chunkIndex]**, when the function reads the sub array it jumps and reads a different address beyond the total array address range, although the indices are correct.

**For reference:**

[image]

---

The  SPMV **kernel** is:

```
void serial_matvec(size_t TS,  double *A, int *JA, int *IA,  double *X, double *Y)
{
    double sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < TS; ++i)
    {   
        sum = 0.0;
        for (int j = IA[i]; j < IA[i + 1]; ++j)
        {
                sum += A[j] * X[JA[j]]; // the error is here , the function reads diffrent 
                                        // address of A,  and JA, so the access 
                                       // will be out-of-bound
            }
            Y[i] = sum;
        }
    }
```

and it is called this way:

```
int chunkIndex = 0;
for(size_t k = 0; k < rows/TS; ++k)
{
    chunkIndex = IA[k * TS];
    serial_matvec(TS, &A[chunkIndex], &JA[chunkIndex], &IA[k*TS], &X[0], &Y[k*TS]);
}
```

assume I process **(8x8) Matrix**, and I process **2 rows per chunk**, so the loop **k** will be r**ows/TS = 4 loops**, the **chunkIndex** and array passed to the function will be as following:

> chunkIndex: 0 --> loop k = 0, &A[0], &JA[0]
>
> chunkIndex: --> loop k = 1, &A[16], &JA[16]   **//[ERROR here, function reads different address]**
>
> chunkIndex: --> loop k = 2, &A[32], &JA[32]   **//[ERROR here, function reads different address]**
>
> chunkIndex: --> loop k = 3, &A[48], &JA[48]   **//[ERROR here, function reads different address]**

When I run the code, only the first chunk executes correctly, the other 3 chunks memory are corrupted and the array pointers jump into boundary beyond the array size.

I've checked all indices manually, of all the parameter, they are all correct, however when I print the addresses they are not the same. (debugging this for 3 days now)

I used `valgrind` and it reported:

> **Invalid read of size 8** and **Use of uninitialised value of size 8** at the **sum += A[j] * X[JA[j]];** line

I compiled it with `-g -fsanitize=address` and I got

> **heap-buffer-overflow**

I tried to access these chunks manually outside the function, and they are correct, so what can cause the heap memory to be corrupted like this ?

The code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hVn8DV), This is the minimum I can do.

Comment: Please post [mcve], we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: In the code you posted, it looks like `chunkIndex` will have the same value each time `serial_matvec` is called, assuming the contents of `block_nnz_count[]` do not change between iterations of the outer loop. Perhaps `chunkIndex` should be initialized to 0 _before_ the outer loop instead of within the outer loop?

Comment: I added the code to the post, I know it is somehow long, but I couldn't find another way to make it shorter

Comment: @IanAbbott you have a point, I changed the 'chunkIndex' to be set to 0 after the 'csr_matvec' call , however it is the same problem.

Comment: In your linked code, these allocations are wrong: `A = (double *)malloc(nnz_M  *sizeof(double*));`, `JA = (int *)malloc(nnz_M * sizeof(int*));`, `IA = (int *)malloc((rows + 1) * sizeof(int*));`. They are using `sizeof(double*)` instead of `sizeof(double)`, etc. Probably other `malloc` calls are also using the wrong sizes. Also, the `memset` call is using the wrong size. It should be `memset(Y, 0, cols * sizeof(*Y));`.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and your debugger

Comment: @IanAbbott I checked this , still the same

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I already did this and included this in my question

Comment: `valgrind` has *a lot* of interesting options. And you could use also the [Address Sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer), probably specific to your compiler

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'll try this, however,  you suggesting that the compiler has a bug ?

Comment: I was wrong about `chunkIndex`. The original version of setting `chunkIndex` works. I can't really spot any problems apart from the incorrect sizes in the `malloc` and `memset` calls, and those will probably not cause problems as long as the size of a pointer is not less than the size of a `double`.

Comment: I checked the malloc with pointer and without pointer, it is the same , I literally checked the indices and addresses manually, and couldn't find something to justify why the sub-array when passed to the function gets corrupted like this.. I appreciated  your help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using global indices (indices inside main) when indexing the portion of the array **(`chunk`)** passed to the function,  hence the out-of-bound problem.

The solution is to start indexing the sub-arrays from **`0`** at each function call, but I had another problem. At each function call, I process **`TS`** rows, each row has different number of non-zeros.

As an example, see the picture, **`chunk 1`**, sorry for my bad handwriting, it is easier this way. As you can see we will need **`3 indices`**, one for the **`TS`** rows proceeded per chunk **`i`** , and the other because each row has different number of non-zeros **`j`**, and the third one to index the sub-array passed **`l`**, which was the original problem. 
[image]

and the **`serial_matvec`** function will be as following:

```
void serial_matvec(size_t TS, const double *A, const int *JA, const int *IA,
                   const double *X, double *Y) {
  int  l = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < TS; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (IA[i + 1] - IA[i]); ++j) {
      Y[i] += A[l] * X[JA[l]];
      l++;
    }    
  }
}
```

The complete code with test is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ZtarJC) If anyone has a more elegant solution, you are more than welcome.